# bash fail passing argument containing space to external script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script call a python script with optional argument. 
when this argument is relevant, it has to be provided with a prefix flag (e.g. `-o "value"`).

Since the value contains space, I've placed quotes around it. However, **in this use case, it's not effective**.

Any hacks to workaround it?

---

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--options', default='', type=str, required=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args.options


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**tests.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

export options="A B C"

export extra_args=""
if [ -n "${options}" ]; then
    export extra_args="${extra_args} -o \"${options}\""
fi

./tests.py $extra_args
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quotes in `${extra_args}` are literal and not interpreted by bash, bash expansions are run once.

It seem's you need an array, also export is only to tell to the shell that the variable must be passed to child process environment.

```
extra_args=()
if [ -n "${options}" ]; then
    extra_args+=( -o "${options}" )
fi

./tests.py "${extra_args[@]}"
```